# Youtube/Google Data API gapi.client undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api, google-api

I am trying to get [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript) example as a spotify app, which i will heavily edit. This should be pretty simple for anyone with real experience in the Youtube Data API. I know there are a few solutions about problems similar to this with the google APIs but all of the solutions seem to be specific to the api...

The specific errors I get right now:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined cb=gapi.loaded_0:6
```

index.html: This normally just loads main.js but to complete this example, I just stripped the code off of the youtube data api example for search.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="buttons">
      <label> <input id="query" value='cats' type="text"/><button id="search-button" disabled onclick="search()">Search</button></label>
    </div>
    <div id="search-container">
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/auth.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/search.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onLoadCallback"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and search.js:

```
function handleAPILoaded() {
  $('#search-button').attr('disabled', false);
}

// Search for a specified string.
function search() {
  var q = $('#query').val();
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
    q: q,
    part: 'snippet'
  });

  request.execute(function(response) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(response.result);
    $('#search-container').html('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
  });
}
```

Comment: Lots of questions come to mind: a) did you add the *.youtube.com and *.google.com domains to your manifest? b) what does your code look like? c) what error do you get?

Comment: alright I added in the requested info. Auth.js looks exactly as it does on the youtube data api example page. And yes i added those two domains to my manifest file. Thanks.