# Spotify Desktop app : content slider doesn't show in app but it shows in Web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications, spotify

I'm developing on Spotify Web App on the desktop.

I'm trying to add Image/contentSlider (Which is use javascript/css and jquery) in WebApp.
I tested on Web browser like google Chrome and Safari. **It works fine.**

but in Spotify App. It doesn't work. It feels like javascript disabled.

Do I need to add something about spotify api to make working fine?

Comment: I believe there has been some restriction of the javascript engine for the CEF that is being used, like reflection is turned off or something.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879289/cannot-load-external-apis-in-index-html is another example of code that works in Chrome but not in an app.

Comment: Although some features are not available in the CEF version used by the Spotify desktop client (Geolocation and Audio API being some of them) there shouldn't be any issue regarding rendering. It would help if you linked or included a sample code that shows the issue.